# Can't remove lines behind SearchResultsTableView cells

Tags: objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm creating an iphone application using Objective-C/Xcode. I have a setup where when I click the search box, the search display view shows up and as I type into the searchbox, the searchDisplayController loads the searchResultsTableView cells with rows consisting of autocomplete terms.

because the results cells are a lot bigger than the autocomplete cells, I have the following to manage row height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return 30;
    } else {
        return 90;
    }
}
```

However I get some weird behavior where the separator lines behind the cells are showing and making an ugly appearance.

(To clarify which separator lines are coming from where, I used

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

)

[image: notice the unwanted grey lines]

Do you know how I could remove/hide these background separator lines from being shown in this view? I've tried various color/transparency and cell size manipulations and searched google/SO but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `tableView` to `style` to `Grouped`

Comment: Not really sure why but your magic spell did the trick thank you! :) 
   (I mean I get that groups changed the style to not have separators but I'm not really sure why I couldn't remove the separators directly)

Comment: Iv'e been having this problem for a long time, not sure why this is happening two..but it works :) glad to help my friend!